# Ocultar td nulla em impressão JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Em meu sistema eu fiz um botão de imprimir uma tela. Está funcionando tudo corretamente, o problema é o seguinte.

Na foto abaixo você pode ver que a parte de Usuario Atual está vindo nulla, pois não tem dados do usuario isto está ok, eu só preciso que quando está usuario atual estiver null (sem dados) ele não exiba na impressão.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isto? está parte de impressão eu fiz em JavaScript. Irei postar o codigo abaixo da foto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**DIV**

```
<div class="modal Detalhes fade" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h3>Detalhes do paciênte!</h3>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="actions" style="float:right;">
                    <button class="ui teal submit button lef print-link" onclick="PrintElem('printOK','Usuário')" id="btnPrint">Imprimir</button>
                    <div class="ui approve green button btn_ok">OK</div>
                </div>
                <br /><br /><br />
                <div class="actions">
                    <div id="printOK">
                        <table style="width:100%" border="1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th id="colAlterado">
                                        Usuário alterado
                                    </th>
                                    <th id="colAtual">
                                        Usuário atual
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="trInser1"></td>
                                    <td id="tdInser2"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Que puxa os dados para a div**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[name="btn_detalhes"]').click(function () {
        var altaUtiId = $(this).attr('id');
        var patientId = $(this).attr('data-content');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Formulario/AltaUTI/VerificaDiff',
            data: { 'PatientId': patientId, 'AltaUtiId': altaUtiId },
            success: function (response) {
                var t1 = response[0];
                var t2 = response[1];
                var registro = response[2];
                if (t1.length > 0 || t2.length > 0) {
                    $('#msgLoading').fadeIn(0);
                    $('.modal.Detalhes').modal({
                        closable: false,
                        blurring: true,
                    }).modal('show');
                    for (var i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
                        $('#trInser1').append('<p> ' + t1[i] + ' </p>');
                        if (t2.length > 0) {
                            $('#tdInser2').append('<p> ' + t2[i] + ' </p>');
                            $('#tdInser2').removeClass('display-none');
                            $('#colAtual').removeClass('display-none');
                        }
                        else {
                            if (registro.length > 0)
                                $('#colAlterado').text('Usuário alterado');
                            else
                                $('#colAlterado').text('Usuário atual');

                            $('#tdInser2').addClass('display-none');
                            $('#colAtual').addClass('display-none');
                        }

                    }
                    $('#msgLoading').fadeOut(0);
                } else {
                    notif({
                        'type': 'error',
                        'msg': 'Não foi encontrado modificações no formulário!',
                        'position': 'center'
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                notif({
                    'type': 'error',
                    'msg': 'Erro na resposta do servidor!',
                    'position': 'center'
                });
            }
        })
    });

    $('.btn_ok').click(function () {
        $("p").remove();

        $('.modal.Detalhes').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

**JavaScript Da Parte de Impressão**

```
//Imprimir o modal gerado
function PrintElem(elem, form) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=500,width=700');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>Relatório de alteração detalhada de dados – ' + document.title + ' </h1>');
    mywindow.document.write('<h2>Formulário: ' + form + '</h2>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

Caso as duas TRs **Usuario Atual** e **Usuario Alterado**, tenham dados ele exibe normalmente como a foto [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, posso dar uma sugestão.
Quando não tiver de mostrar, coloca uma classe personalizada como `class="nao-mostrar"`, não deve ser problema em .js.

Crie o seguinte num css:

```
@media print {
 *{
  visibility: visible;
};

.nao-mostrar{visibility: hidden;}

}
```

veja se funciona....